# How to assign Elementor template to only FIRST page of archive/category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

Hi I am working on an woocommerce sitte called https://indicbrands.com/ where I am using elementor plugin of WordPress to assign a custom page to Product Category, but here I want to assign a template to a category only for the first page.

For example I want to assign a "women's fashion" template file to  https://indicbrands.com/product-category/fashion/ but NOT to https://indicbrands.com/product-category/fashion/?product-page=2. I mean from page 2 onwards I want to have the theme's default category template.

**How to achieve this?**

Currently, I have created a block named "all product in women's fashion clothing" with pagination on to at least keep the other products in the category linked with the current template, but when we go to the second page, the applied template keep loading.

Comment: Ironically, your username is the reason I have voted to close your question.  Please provide some useable details that would make this question on topic.

Comment: you are right that I should have given a valid example using code but I have build the page in elementor which advertise build without code, also it has a configuration to display it in specific category but not sure about specific page of the category if pagination is applied!

Comment: So there are two questions, 1st if we can achieve something like this without code, or 2nd if with code, then how? actually in woocommerce tag i seen many questions where it was simple configuration and no code was required , even in answers.

Comment: In your archive, you can use hte dynamic conditions plugin, to listen for a request parameter - set that parameter as `paged` to hide everything - make the standard template below, and listen for the same parameter, so show the standard section.. That could be the "No code" way

Comment: So - you are still using the same template - But a different section of it - This requires the following plugins - Elementor, Ele custom skin and dynamic conditions.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I will get this asap.

Comment: @Stender: Thanks, this worked liked a charm, i have to struggle little bit to find exact custom tag but there is one dynamic tags plugin which did the magic by giving me exact request parameter!  

Please add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From the comments

In your archive, you can use the dynamic conditions plugin, to listen for a request parameter - set that parameter as paged to hide everything - make the standard template below, and listen for the same parameter, so show the standard section.. That could be the "No code" way

So - you are still using the same template - But a different section of it - This requires the following plugins - Elementor, Ele custom skin and dynamic conditions.